# The unstopable Loop X(

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is actually my very first code. Im trying to add new posts to my Wordpress Site. 
 **Mysql query will return 4035 rows** that have all the details to insert the new post.

The problem : **Loop wont ever stop!** *It will reach 4035 row and then start all over from the 1st row*

Things I tried to make it stop:

1. Added - `if ($loopstimes > 4400) {break;}`
2. Limited mysql query to 4050 rows

The weird parts:

1. When i limit mysql query to `LIMIT 900`, Everything works **PERFECTLY**. The loop stops when 900 post are added, if i add 950, the script will add 943 posts and then will give me `Fatal error "Maximum execution time reached"`. Then the script stops.
2. I increase the "Maximum execution time" to **300 Sec** and increase the memory from 128 to 256MB, i use my query without LIMIT and then the Loop wont ever stop.

Is my code problematic? Or is server issue?

```
<?PHP 
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$loopstimes = 0;

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("xxxx_xxxx",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select examples");

//execute the SQL query and return records
// Query to get all names
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT names_list.* ... LIMIT 4050");

if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

//fetch the data from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $p_name= $row["p_name"];
    $category= $row["gcategory"];
    $subcategory= $row["subcategory"];
    $ase_date= $row["ase_date"];

    //Fix the (') to prepare it for mysql query

    $pp_name = $p_name; 
    $newp_name = str_replace("'","''",$p_name);

    //Query to count results
    $minprice = mysql_query("SELECT ... WHERE Product_p_name = '$newp_name' AND ORDER BY product_price_usd");
    $countss = mysql_num_rows($minprice);

    if($minprice === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }

    $rowm = mysql_fetch_array($minprice);
    $minprice = '$'.$rowm["product_price_usd"];

    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'My title...',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    // Add Advanced Custom field values
    update_field( "field_552fc3f84b43r", $p_name, $post_id ); 

    //Regex the date to keep just the year
    if (preg_match("/20.*/", $ase_date, $matches)) {
        $ase_year = $matches[0];
    }

    //Insert Tags for Custom Taxonomies

    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $audio_subcategory, 'subcategory-cpt', false );
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $fex_pro_rg, 'fex-pro-cpt', false );

    $loopstimes++;

    if ($loopstimes > 4400) {break;}
    echo 'Post added!, '.$post_id.'<br>';
    echo $loopstimes;
}

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
echo 'Finish';
?>
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: first of all try to use mysqli_* because mysql_* is depricated now.

Comment: Chuck Norris eats `mysql_*` functions for breakfast.

Comment: Without seeing the SQL statement that is feeding the `while` loop I'm not sure we can really answer this

Answer (score 0):

Sure you already know that you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions anymore.

But just to help you pass over the issue right now:

```
//Query to count results
$minprice_query_result = mysql_query("SELECT ... WHERE Product_p_name = '$newp_name' AND ORDER BY product_price_usd");
$countss = mysql_num_rows($minprice_query_result);

if($minprice_query_result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

$rowm = mysql_fetch_array($minprice_query_result);
$minprice = '$'.$rowm["product_price_usd"];

mysql_free_result ( $minprice_query_result );
```

And by the way, why do you need this subquery? to get `$minprice = '$'.$rowm["product_price_usd"];` ? but you never use that variable in your code!

Comment: Thanks for your time, well the $minprice i use it in a custom field. I have up to 10 custom fields like     **update_field( "field_552fc3*****", $minprice, $post_id );** That i remove them from the current code just to keep it smaller. Ill try your suggestion and tell you if works asap.

Comment: you can't post not full fragment of code to get real help. Nobody can help if you hide part of your code.

Comment: I did change what you suggested but the script gave me warrnings. I downloaded the whole website + dbases and install it on my pc with xampp. I used my original code and the scrip works Perfect. So now i believe the problem is the host, any idea what might cause this endless loop?

Comment: did you do my suggestion? to rename variable and free mysql results?

Answer (score 0):

I run the script using XAMPP and it worked perfect. To me, that means my code is correct and the problem is with my host.
The way i solved this issue was to LIMIT 500 and updated mysql query to exclude the names that was already a post assigned with. Then i run the script X times till all names was assigned to a post.

BTW i changed from mysql_* to mysqli_*
Thanks for the advice!